# Simple image caching using dictionaries, what are the downsides?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I've got a simple caching class to handle caching images that are loaded in through `Firebase`:

```
import UIKit

final class Cache {
  static let sharedInstance = Cache()
  private init() {}
  private var images = [String: UIImage]()

  func cacheImage(image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
    images[key] = image
  }

  func fetchImageWithKey(key: String) -> UIImage? {
    return images[key]
  }
}
```

It works with a sample size of 20 images for my `UITableView`. I understand that I'll need to also handle cases where this cache is consuming too much memory, like purging the cache.

Assuming I do that, are there any obvious flaws in this method?

Comment: You can save yourself some leg work and use NSCache, depending on your flow you may want to save images to disk and then load them as needed into cache, then check the cache and if they aren't there load from disk using something like the ImageIO framework.

Comment: I agree with @thefredelement. The obvious flaw is that you're reinventing a wheel. Apple's own classes are going to do this much better than you can. IIRC there is a good WWDC 2015 on this topic.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the heads up on `NSCache`. Just tried it out by swapping my dictionary for `NSCache`. Works like a charm. Thank you @matt @thefredelement.